# Kubernetes Image goes into CrashLoopBackoff even if entry point is defined

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to run an image using Kubernetes with below Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6.9

COPY rpms/* /tmp/
RUN yum -y localinstall /tmp/*
ENTERYPOINT service test start && /bin/bash
```

Now when I try to deploy this image using `pod.yml` as shown below,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    app: testpod
  name: testpod
spec:
  containers:
  - image: test:v0.2
    name: test
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /data
      name: testpod
  volumes:
  - name: testod
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: testpod
```

Now when I try to create the pod the image goes into a crashloopbackoff. So how I can make the image to wait in /bin/bash on Kubernetes as when I use `docker run -d test:v0.2` it work fines and keep running.

Comment: are you using minikube?

Comment: what is the error log?

Comment: I am using google kubernetes platform.

Comment: Error is `State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0\n Normal   Created                2s (x4 over 54s)  kubelet,   Created container
  Normal   Started                2s (x4 over 53s)  kubelet,   Started container
  Warning  BackOff                0s (x5 over 50s)  kubelet,   Back-off restarting failed container
  Warning  FailedSync             0s (x5 over 50s)  kubelet,   Error syncing pod`

Comment: Run a script in ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: @aerokite can you please provide an example as I was running a script which create some softlinks and then start the service. And then run shell as front process but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a terminal to the running container. When starting a pod using `kubectl run ...` you can use `-i --tty` to do that. In the pod yml filke, you can add the following, to the container spec to attach tty.

```
stdin: true 
tty: true
```

Comment: This solution worked for me with ```CMD bash``` instead of ```ENTRYPOINT```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a command like `tail -f /dev/null` to keep your container always be **on**, this could be done inside your `Dockerfile` or in your `Kubernetes yaml` file.